# Book recommendation for self-studying abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have searched for getting an information to select textbook for abstract algebra by myself. Now I have three candidates for my abstract algebra text.

(So far, I have learned one-year linear algebra and undergraduate level analysis)

I really appreciate for you to help me select a nice textbook.

1. Stephen Lovett, Abstract Algebra: Structures and Applications
2. P.B. Bhattacharya, S.K. Jain, S.R. Nagpaul, Basic Abstract Algebra
3. David S. Dummit, Richard M. Foote, Abstract Algebra

Could you give me an recommendation for choosing textbook with the reason why you recommend that book?(If you have another nice textbook, tell me your another recommended book.)

Comment: For a very accessible (and cheap) one, look at Pinter's book. Your third choice is most popular, but I am not sure how I feel about it as a self-study book.

Comment: I think Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* is good for self study, provided you do a significant fraction of the exercises.  (I guess that goes without saying.)

Comment: @Moo Thank you for your advice, I think I can get more information from the post you linked.

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for your new recommendation, I will check that book